# How to download mongo db dump? I can access server via pem file

Tags: mongodb, pem, mongodump, mongorestore

I need to download dump of a mongodb database from a server, and restore it to my local. The server is accessible via ssh using pem file.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a way to create and download dump of a remote mongo database via a single command.

However, it is possible to connect to server with using pem via ssh, export database dump, exit from server, and download the dump files from server to local via scp.

If this method is ok for you, here are the steps for it:

1) You can connect to server using pem via ssh

```
$ ssh -i /path/to/pem/<file_name>.pem <username>@<domain_or_IP>
```

2) Than, you can export dump files on server via mongodump

```
username@domain:~$ mongodump --db <db_name>
```

3) After that, you can exit ssh connection and download dump files to local via scp

```
$ scp -i /path/to/pem/<file_name>.pem -r <username>@<domain_or_IP>:~/dump/<db_name> ~/dump/.
```

4) Finally,  you can restore the dump files via mongorestore

```
$ mongorestore --db <db_name> ~/dump/<db_name>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does, now how can we restore to any online DB?

Comment: Hi @Habib,

Sorry, I just recognized your question.

If I understand your question, your are trying to load your db data to a database located on a remote server rather than localhost.

If so,  you need to login your remote server before step 3, such as using following ssh command;
$ ssh -u <my_user> -p <my_passwors>

Then, you should be able to continue as in step 3 and 4.